# Case and When query give me both column filled

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 table

```
Groupes=> GroupsId/GroupeName
Member =>MemberId/MemberName
Subscribed=>GroupeId/MemberId/Date
Unsubscribed=>GroupeId/MemberId/Date
```

NB:members in subscribed table not listed in unsubscribed table and vice versa.

Please i want to display data like this

```
Groups - MemberName - Subscribed - Date     -   Unsubscribed - Date
Grp1   - Jhon       -     1      - 12/12/18 -        0       - NULL
Grp1   - Mike       -     0      - NULL     -        1       - 18/12/18
Grp2   - Jhon       -     1      - 12/12/18 -        0       - NULL
Grp2   - Mike       -     0      - NULL     -        1       - 18/12/18
```

Ect ...
Please anyone can help me with this query i tried case when but i get both Subscribed column filled and Unsubscribed column filled

Thanks a lot

Comment: What query? It seems you forgot to post it when you posted your "question". :) What is your question by the way?

Comment: You need 4 case statements. One for each column (subscribed, date, unsubscribes, date)

Comment: Please clearly provide all the table definitions including columns, which are the primary keys and some sample data for each as well as the actual query you have tried thus far.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "but i get both Subscribed column filled and Unsubscribed column filled" - your sample output clearly has both filled with either a 1 or a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.  Combine the subscribers and unsubscribers tables first.  Then bring in the other information:

```
select g.groupname, m.membername, su.*
from (select groupid, memberid, max(subscribed) as subscribed, max(sdate) as sdate, max(unsubscribed) as unsubscribed, max(udate) as udate
        from ((select groupid, memberid, 1 as subscribed, date as sdate, 0 as unsubscribed, null as udate
               from subscribed s
              ) union all
              (select groupid, memberid, 0 as subscribed, null as sdate, 1 as unsubscribed, date as udate
              from subscribed s
             )
            ) su
       group by groupid, memberid
      ) join
     groups g
     on g.groupid = su.groupid join
     member m
     on m.memberid = su.memberid;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon that's give me a hint how to do it, very helpful